# Unity 2D - Problem with player running ON wall instead of falling

Tags: unity, collision-detection

I´m having a problem with my game (yes, I'm new with Unity). 
I'm trying to make a simple 2d platformer and I ran into this situation:

[Youtube Link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_VwhghR60LE)

As you can see, when the player hits the BoxCollider from the side, it tries to get a hold of it instead of just keep going down...

These are the properties of my player:
[image]

And the block only has the default box collider.

Any ideas? 
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you are returning grounded when against a wall so you are able to see a walk animation and also jump.

If you are using a ground layer to determine the ground then just create the walls on a different layer so you will not return grounded and will fall normally.

Adding a slipping effect using a physics material on a collider could also work around that issue if you are not using layers.